# latexdiff trips over hskip

Tags: spacing, latexdiff, compilation-error

I have a bibliography of a document in a style that produces lines like these in the bbl file:

```
.\hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Springer
```

When using `latexdiff` on documents where one of these lines has been added or removed compared to the previous version, markup like this is generated by `latexdiff`:

```
\DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{.}\hskip \DIFadd{1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em}\relax \DIFadd{Springer}\DIFaddend
```

Clearly, `latexdiff` sees the values after `\hskip` as differences and tries to apply markup to them. Using `--exclude-textcmd="hskip"` or `--exclude-safecmd="hskip"` does not change the behavior. Obviously, the diff cannot be processed by `pdflatex`:

> Missing number, treated as zero.

If it was only one line, I would edit it by hand, but there are several in my document. Is there any `latexdiff` option or automatic workaround which allows me to produce a valid diff file?

Comment: `\hskip` shouldn't be in a latex document so shouldn't be an issue for latexdiff, the latex syntax is `\hspace{1em plus  0.5em minus 0.4em}` where the argument is delimited in `{}` so most likely a lot easier for latexdiff to handle

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Maybe it has to do with the IEEE style that I am using in this document. Is there a way to force the `{}` in the bbl output?

Comment: If you are using a publisher supplied bst style and that is inserting \hskip then there is not a lot you can do (you may not be allowed to use an edited style)

Comment: You could automate @DavidCarlisle's suggestion by changing the commands with a script in the bbl file (on Unix): `sed 's/hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em/hspace{1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em}/' yourfile.bbl > tmp.bbl ; mv tmp.bbl yourfile.bbl` or similar.  Also,  you could apply latexdiff only to the manuscript file, not the bbl file (i.e. do not use --flatten)

Comment: The spaces are always different and only some are surrounded by `DIFadd` commands. I am currently trying to figure out a regex to catch and fix them. Too bad that the style is misbehaving.

Comment: You must do these substitutions before processing with latexdiff, otherwise it will be a mess to deal with. What about "hskip ([0-9.]*)em plus ([0-9.]*)em minus ([0-9.])em" for a regex? The parentheses () capture the content, which can be accessed by $1, $2, $3 in substitution string (at least this works with the perl substitutions, but I think it should work with sed, too

Comment: @frederik: I am aware of that. It seems that the style is even more complicated than that, though. Once I have a solution, i will post it here.

Comment: I found a solution, but it is really ugly: First, I add {} around hskip of both bbl files. Then I run latexdiff. On the resulting file, I remove the {} around hskip again. I don't know why, but the final document only builds without the {}.